# UIImageView in custom UITableViewCell resizing upon click

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a custom UI table view cell, upon clicking it, the UIImageView within the cell resizes, and the previous styling (e.g rounded corners), which is defined in cellForRowAt, is lost upon the click. Please see image attached.[image]

Code referring to profile image view in cellForRowAt

```
  cell.profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profileImageView.frame.height/2
        cell.profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Code from didSelectRow

```
let message = downloadedmessages![indexPath.row] as! ALMessage

let displayVC : ChatViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatViewController") as! ChatViewController
displayVC.sender = msgUser(senderId: ALUserDefaultsHandler.getUserId(), displayName: ALUserDefaultsHandler.getDisplayName())
displayVC.reciever = msgUser(senderId: message.to, displayName: message.name)
navigationController?.pushViewController(displayVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: can you please add some code .?

Comment: Please add `didSelectRowAt()` code!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `contentMode` of `profileImageView`, i.e

```
profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Also, add the proper `height` and `width` `constraints` of the `profileImageView` in the `.xib`.

**Note:** `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` is not the right place to add cell's `layer` properties in case you're reusing the same cell. That must be added in `awakeFromNib()` method, i.e.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    UIImageView().contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profileImageView.frame.height/2
}
```